# existence of solution of $Ax= \max(b-x,0) $

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

How do you prove the existence of a solution to the linear system: 
\begin{equation}
Ax= \max(b-x,0)
\end{equation}

A is an $n\times n$ matrix and $b$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  $x$ is the unknown vector.

I am not sure how to work with the max. Or can we actually solve it.

I also read about Galerkin method which could work, so by finding a sequence of vectors $x_n$ satisfying the equation and show the convergence? I tried that but kind of lost somewhere, not really familiar with the method.

Comment: how are you defining $max(b-x,0)$? Is it componentwise comparison between $b-x$ and $0$ vector? or something else?

Comment: Yes it is componentwise comparison between b-x and 0 vector

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A = -1$, $b=1$, then the equation $Ax = \max(b-x,0)$ has no solution.

(To see this, note that the equation is $-x = \max(1-x,0)$, hence a solution must be non-positive, however a non-positive $x$ results in a positive right hand side which is a contradiction.)